Is the MITM protection provided by BLE LESC passkey mechanism bidirectional?
I'm trying to understand whether the passkey mechanism described in BLE LESC pairing provides bidirectional MITM protection.
As far as I understand, A and B will generate the same shared secret using Diffie-Hellman. Depending on the IOCaps, one side will display the passkey (let's assume this is A) and the other one (B) will receive it via an out-of-band means of communication, which we assume is inaccessible to the attacker. Usually, A has a display and B has a keyboard. This implies physical proximity and thus some degree of protection.
Thinking of a naïve implementation, you would expect the passkey to be calculated as a hash of A's public key or of the shared secret, so that B can verify that no MITM was involved during the DH exchange. This means that only B has assurance that A is in physical proximity, but not the other way round, because an attacker trying to impersonate B could just skip the verification. A doesn't know if the other side is in physical proximity or not.
However, I remember reading that this authentication mechanism was bidirectional, so I'm guessing that either that was not true or the implementation is different to what I've described. Nonetheless, I can't think a way of doing it nor make sense of the BLE standard description.
Thanks!
